# Insert the cell value inside of the condition in order to use with the loop in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I need some professional help. I have a task for some data base, it´s a huge one with more than 270.000 lines. The thing is that i need to extract some data in order to apply it for the next step code.

i get:

```
    select(filter(datos_inversion, ANYO == i, CODUNIDAD == 76, CODNIV1 == 9, CODNIV2 == 2000, CODNIV4 == 1000, CODNIV3 %in% c(2017, 2019, 2023), CODNIV5 %in% c(1002, 1056, 1057)), VALOR = VALOR)
```

which helps me to extract a needed column from a data frame, the thing is that i need to repeat the same code, but with the changing of the variable "ANYO" which means the year, for the upcoming number (for example, if this time in "ANYO" was used the year 1985, for the next code execution i need to have 1986, but i must NOT do it manually, bc i have it from 1964 to 2015, it´d be a disaster to do it manually. So just should be changed "i" anytime the code executed again and again inside the loop). Also my task includes to write the loop for it, but which one is better, i have no clue... If someone could really help, woud be fantastic!

Thanks everyone in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of alternatives, but you could use
`lapply` function from base `R` for that.

```
years <- 1964:2015
output <- lapply(years, function(i) yourFunction(i))
names(output) <- as.character(years)
```

The element `output` is a list of dataframes, and you can access each element of this list by doing:

```
output[["yearOfInterest"]]
```

Comment: Are you sure that `lapply` is from the `plyr` package?

Comment: No, sorry. I made a mistake! I will edit my answer. Thanks @www!

Comment: @JFraper thank you very much! the only thing is that I'm not getting how to use it afterward.. in the place of **yourFunction** I put my variant **select...** it outputted the list of 52 characters, and then how to apply it to the function I already have? bc, it gives me an error  **Evaluation error: object 'i' not found.**. What to do this case? And back then how to use it repeatedly for each of the years? If you could explain this, please 

Comment: if you want to apply a second function to the outputs, you can include it in the `lapply`, this way: `lapply(years, function(i) yourSecondFunction(yourSelectFunction(i)))`; alternatively, you can write a second `lapply` line where the input is the `output` element: lapply(output, function(x) yourSecondFunction(x))

Comment: @JFraper thank you, man, it works!!